# how to parse my data in wordpress gravity form

Tags: wordpress

```
   <td> <?php echo $row->title; ?> </td>
   <td> <?php echo $row->user_name; ?> </td>
   <td> <?php echo $row->user_last_name; ?> </td>
   <td> <?php echo $row->user_address; ?> </td>
   <td><?php echo $row->user_email; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row->game_name; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row->score; ?></td> 
   <td><?php echo $row->time; ?></td>
```

i have some data like  this [1](http://clip2net.com/s/3aX9p3T)   how i can
 parse  this in  gravity form in wordpress

Answer (score 0):

If, by "parse", you mean have those fields pre-populated in your form page, you can use Gravityforms Post Custom Field option. This feature allows you to pass PHP vars to the form via a POST, shortcode or hooks. The process is well documented. You can read more here:

```
http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Post_Custom_Field
```